# jquery, replace multiple elements recursively

Tags: jquery

I got stuck with the following issue.
I'm explaining some content by footnotes. The footnotes e.g. **[10]** have the format `<sup>[10]</sup>`. [screenshot of content with footnotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovY5K.png)

I'm trying to replace `<sup>[10]</sup>` with `<a href="#m10" data-toggle="modal"><sup>[10]</sup></a>` by using the following jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $(function(){
        var s = $('sup').html().slice(1, -1);
        $("sup").replaceWith('<a href="#m'+s+'" data-toggle="modal"><sup>['+s+']</sup></a>');
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Unfortunately this code replaces all footnotes with the same/FIRST found footnote - in this case, all footnotes are replaced with "10" (see screenshot). I want to recursively replace each footnote.

I don't know how to solve this problem got stuck for several days. Perhaps anybody of you guys or girls can help me.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't; you explicitly replace them all. Wouldn't you want to iterate over the `<sup>` you found and update each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over each of the `sup` elements and replace the corresponding HTML rather than replacing *all* the `sup` elements. Inside of the `.each()` method, `this` refers to the current `sup` element.

Based on the jQuery you provided, you probably want:

```
$('sup').each(function() {
  var s = this.textContent.slice(1, -1);

  $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#m' + s + '" data-toggle="modal"><sup>[' + s + ']</sup></a>');
});
```

Rather than using `.slice()`, you could also just extract the digit(s) using the `.match()` method:

```
$('sup').each(function() {
  var s = this.textContent.match(/\d+/)[0];

  $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#m' + s + '" data-toggle="modal"><sup>[' + s + ']</sup></a>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('sup').each(function () {
  $(this).wrap('<a href="#m' + $(this).html().slice(1, -1) + '" data-toggle="modal"></a>');
});
```

Take a look at the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method. The problem is your code only runs once, not in the context of each occurrence of `<sup>`

Comment: 1+ - Using `.wrap()` is definitely cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use iterator. Try following

```
$('sup').each(function(){
var s = $(this).html().slice(1, -1);
    $(this).wrap('<a href="#m'+s+'" data-toggle="modal"></a>');

});
```

References - [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)